# Ideal Scala's compiler and libraries using Play framework

Tags: scala, compiler-construction, playframework-2.0

I've just downloaded Play Framework 2.1-RC1.

Within folders, I noticed that SBT folder includes itself Scala's compiler/library whose version is:

**scala.2.10.0-RC1**.

Previously, I used to compile some Scala programs with the more recent version:

**scala.2.10.0-RC2**

Should I stay with **scala.2.10.0-RC1** provided by Play (in order to avoid potential incompatibility with Play)?

Further, is there a way (a specific Play's command-line?) to add automatically src-jars for Scala into Play's SBT folder (scala-library-src.jar etc...)? Indeed the folder structure contains currently only jars files:

- jansi.jar
- jline.jar
- scala-compiler.jar
- scala-library.jar
- scala-reflect.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Scala 2.10.0 final](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/27499) has been out for about a week, now. I'd expect that the Play artifacts are available for it by now and if they're not they surely will be soon.